# Can't center align Pager Numbers in a Gridview

Tags: css, asp.net

My Gridview page numbers appear to the left hand side. I have tried everything as you can see below to center them on the screen but it won't move..

```
<PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" PageButtonCount="25" />
<PagerStyle cssClass="pagernumcenter" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
```

CSS..

```
.pagernumcenter {
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
vertical-align:center;
horizontal-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

set gridview's pagerStyle="myPager"
and create a css style (please refence attached image)

Comment: you can also set <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />